# MVC controller wants empty contructor but then Interface is not used and throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am getting this error:

`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PubStuff.Intern.Web.Internal.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
public class InternController : BaseController
{
    IInternService _internService;


    public InternController() { }

    public InternController(IInternService internService)
    {
        _internService = internService;
    }


    // GET: Intern
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        object responseObject = null;


        responseObject = _internService.GetAllSkills();

        return View();
    }
}
```

1. It complains If I do not have empty constructor
2. Once there IS an empty contructor then this line `responseObject = _internService.GetAllSkills();` throws the error.

_internService is null

**How do I fix this?**  **What are the problem(s)?**

**Updates**
I end up having a problem with **StructureMap** whether I add **IInternUnitOfWork** or NOT.

I added the `IInternService` to StructureMap and then doesn't help

**Error thrown**

```
protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
                       ? this.Container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
                       : this.Container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }

        return this.Container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    }
```

`"StructureMap Exception Code:  202\nNo Default Instance defined for PluginFamily PublicHealth.Intern.DataAccess.Contracts.IInternUnitOfWork, PublicHealth.Intern.DataAccess.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}`

Comment: What DI framework are you using to inject the the service?

Comment: I assume the fact that it wants a default constructor means that somewhere your code (or autogenerated / library code) references a default constructor. Since that constructor doesn't initialize _internService, it makes sense that you would get a null reference from trying to call it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke   -  StructureMap  - old version ( 2.6.1)  I hate it

Comment: @nhouser9     How do I track something like this down?

Comment: Looks like the dependency injection is failing and either doesn't send anything or ends up invoking the default constructor. In any case, in the event your dependency injection fails, it should be caught at that point... else you'll have to put in something in the default constructor that initializes that object.

Comment: @TimothyFisher Where do you call the constructor?

Comment: @nhouser9    with url      http://localhost/PubStuff.Intern.Web.Internal/intern

Comment: Okay, your error message is pretty clear now. You have not mapped `IInternUnitOfWork` to a concrete type that implements it. Make sure the concrete type actually implements this interface. If you continue having issues, post the relevant registration code here so we can see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have been burned by the "No default constructor" error message. When using DI, this does **NOT** mean you should add an empty constructor.

```
public InternController() { }
```

In fact, [using multiple constructors with DI is anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

This error message means that your DI container is *not plugged into MVC*, and therefore MVC cannot resolve your constructor parameters through the DI container. You need to add the line to plug it in that looks like this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory(container));
```

OR

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
```

One of these lines needs to be in your application startup code inside of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), just after you register the types with StructureMap.

Comment: I know that StructureMap is for sure getting called, but somehow the mappings must not be correct.  I don't map in the IInternService ,  but rather I have  IPubDbContext ..  and IInternUnitofWork etc...

Comment: OIC. Some people have reported that some DI containers that are not configured correctly can *also* throw this exception. One thing you can do to "divide and conquer" is to try to resolve the controller directly through StructureMap *right after your application startup code* (as a temporary test). `var x = container.Resolve<InternController>();`.

Answer (score -1):

You need an empty constructor, so try this:

```
public InternController():this(new  MyInternService())
{
}
```

Where `MyInternService` is your default `IInternService` implementation (ie, the `IInternService` you will use in production).

This pattern is most used to feed a controller with "testing" data and to be able to change some definitions on call, like using testing frameworks.

Comment: Just forgot: This will call your second constructor with an implementation of IInternService (MyInternService )

Comment: Not sure I follow.   InternService does implement IInterService interface  , but if i do this   `public InternController() : this(new InternService()) {  }`   That does not work

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'internUnitOfWork' of 'InternService.InternService(IInternUnitOfWork)' PubStuff.Intern.Web.Internal C:\IPAA\Main\Src\PubStuffIntern\PubStuff.Intern.Web.Internal\Controllers\InternController.cs 19 Active